# Is Anaconda overriding my python version?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to run the latest version of python. I downloaded the latest version of python off the website. When I run the following line of code I see an Anaconda version:

```
python --version

Python 3.6.10 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

I feel that the problem is that it is using an Anaconda version. How do I navigate out of this to the latest version?

I am using a Mac

Comment: are you using mac or PC? it matters...look up how to work with PATH and env variables Per Mac or PC. you will need to know this crap on a PC on a Mac...everything just works.

Comment: this is on a Mac

Comment: I install 2 to 3 kinds of Python on the same computer. like python 2.7 and 3.8. also, Most developers use this virtualenv to create a new virtual place for code and only need to install dependencies 1 time per project

Comment: Also, what would you say the latest version of python is? i would go with what ever Anaconda comes with personally. For mac Python comes out of the box. Maybe uninstall anaconda, upgrade python, test it out. then in stall anaconda. Finally, upgrade anaconda to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I went online and realized I had to deactivate conda with the following line:

```
conda deactivate
```